# How do I set node options in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to increase node's http-max-header-size in firebase, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

Is this even possible?

For example, if I was trying to run a node application, I would run it like this:

`node --http-max-header-size=80000 my_program.js`

This is to solve an HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW on http requests with large headers.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?  What would you do if your code wasn't running in Cloud Functions?

Comment: @DougStevenson edited

Answer (score 0):

With Cloud Functions, it's not possible to adjust the arguments that would be passed to the node process that executes the function.  You might want to look into using a different HTTP client whose options you can control through code.

Comment: It's a node restriction